# Error in COBOL program

Tags: cobol

SO I am learning COBOL for my job. This is my first program and I am already stuck 
The aim of my program is to accept the name and date and display it.
The code is as such

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. PROG.
DATA DIVISION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
77 NAME     PIC X(6)
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
DISPLAY 'Enter name(6 char max)'.
ACCEPT NAME.
DISPLAY 'Name is',NAME.
DISPLAY 'Date is', DATE.
STOP RUN.
```

I am using this compiler http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cobol_online.php and getting this error
     sh-4.3$ cobc -x -free *.cobc -o main
        main.cobc:6: Error: syntax error, unexpected PROCEDURE, expecting EXTERNAL or GLOBAL

Any idea?

Comment: One question though - I've tried your compiler page and never get anything beyond a 'waiting' spinner - what configuration do you use to utilize this page?

Comment: Attempting to close as a typo. You line which defines the data (`77 NAME...` needs a full-stop/period. You may remove all the full-stops/periods in for procedure verbs, then just finish your program with a line with a single full-stop/period. You can download GnuCOBOL for free (the new name for OpenCOBOL) and avoid the limitations of that site (like being able to use files). It's at SourceForge.Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every line but one has a period (the line before your error)

Plus, I'll point you back to your own referenced website : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cobol/cobol_program_structure.htm

Answer (score 1):

Here is compiled code:

.(dot) missed after X(6) and indentation also matters.

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. PROG.
DATA DIVISION.
    WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
    77 NAME     PIC X(6).
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
    DISPLAY 'Enter name(6 char max)'.
    ACCEPT NAME.
    DISPLAY 'Name is ', NAME.
    DISPLAY 'Date is ', FUNCTION CURRENT-DATE.
STOP RUN.
```

Comment: Just to be clear, since `-free` is being specified, indentation only matters for readability. It doesn't affect code interpretation in this case. This program will properly compile even all left-justified as the OP had it (although I'm certainly not advocating lack of indentation!).